# How can I create a custom "search" for my site?

Tags: javascript, search

On my site, I collect information on items in a game I play.  I would like to implement some sort of custom search for the items that is both easier to use, and displays the result in a more aesthetic manner.

Currently, I use a wikidot site which allows tags to be assigned to pages and they *can* be searched, but searching multiple tags doesn't work as I would like.  It will start the list with pages with all the tags, then pages that have one of the tags, and finally pages that just happen to have the tags in the body.  Also, the results are presented as the page title, the first few lines of text from each page (without any line breaks making it hard to read), and finish with a link to the page.  [See example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Sm6.jpg ] What I would like for the results are something like the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5ly1.jpg, which is an actual page from my site, but it's not dynamic, I must edit that page if I want to keep it up to date; and for any permutations of tags I want to create a page like that for, I need to first find all of the relevant items, organize them how I want, then make the page containing the includes for each of their individual pages (each item has its own page, I just put an [[include item-name]] wherever I want that item to show up on other pages, which just puts the body of the page in.

What I'm looking for is the best plan of action to make this happen.  I'm familiar with HTML/CSS/JS, but not much other webdev related stuff.  Is there a way I could have a page with a comma separated list that I could parse with JavaScript to search pages?  Or if should I look elsewhere, what are some good tutorials or quality sources to read up on how to do this?

Thank you in advanced for any answers you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you still require help with this, I'd suggest asking on the Wikidot community wiki instead, as there are more people able to help you with your question there (as you have a Wikidot site).

URL: http://community.wikidot.com/forum